# Are inner products always dominated by the norm of tensor products?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Prove or disprove the following possible generalization of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $A_1, \dots A_n, B_1, \dots B_n \in H$. Then

$|\sum_{i=1}^{n} \langle A_i, B_i \rangle| \leq || \sum_{i=1}^{n} A_i \otimes B_i ||$

where the norm is in the tensor Hilbert space $H \hat{\otimes} H$. In essence we are asking whether a bunch of inner products are always dominated by the norm of the corresponding tensor products.

I say that it is a generalization of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality because if one takes $n=1$ above, one gets

$|\langle A_1, B_1\rangle| \leq ||A_1 \otimes B_1||=||A_1||||B_1||$

which is the familiar Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. I have tried applying standard tricks used to prove Cauchy-Schwarz, such as using the fact that the norm of $A \wedge B = A\otimes B - B \otimes A$ is non-negative but to no avail.

Comment: Is it really a generalization of Cauchy-Schwarz?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @timur I have edited the question to answer your comment. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have tried to phrase the question better. Do you think this is sufficient?

Comment: @kgw1984 Yes, I do.

Comment: I think the answer is positive. Use the fact that $A \otimes B$ can be identified with the rank one operator $x \mapsto \langle A, x \rangle B$ and the map $A \otimes B \mapsto \langle A, B \rangle$ is just the trace. So you want to bound the trace. Equivalently, you can use the self-duality of $H$ and the fact that every norm lifts to the projective tensor.

Answer (score 1):

Given a Banach space $X$, the quadratic form $q: X \times X^\ast \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $q(x,x^\ast) = \langle x, x^\ast \rangle$ is bounded. Indeed, it is contractive. Therefore it lifts to the projective tensor product $q: X \hat\otimes X^\ast \to \mathbb{C}$. Now, use that, when $X$ is a Hilbert space you have self-duality.

Another approach is that you can identify $H \hat\otimes H$ with the [trace class operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class) $S^1[H] \subset B(H)$. It is easy to check that
$$
  \mathrm{Tr} ( A \otimes B ) = \langle A, B \rangle.
$$
So you only need to see that the trace is bounded in $S^1[H]$, which follows by definition.

Comment: I think your answer is correct. Do you think one can come up with necessary and sufficient conditions for equality in terms of $A_i$ and $B_i$?

Comment: Yes. Positivity of the element $S = \sum_k A_k \otimes B_k$ as an operator in $H$.

Comment: I think one can identify $H\hat{\otimes}H$ with the space of Hilbert-Schmidt operators and not trace-class operators, but I guess it makes no difference because we are interested in finite-rank operators. Do you think one can derive the result from more elementary considerations? Also, I can't understand the first answer. Can you give me a good reference to look up the relevant results on quadratic forms in Banach space and lifting?

Comment: It does make a difference because the norms would be different. The Hilbert-Schmidt operators form a self-dual space, but the dual of $H \hat\otimes H$, for finite dimensional $H$ is given by $H \otimes_\epsilon H$, which can be identified with $B(H)$, a notoriously nonreflexive space. Just look in Ryan's Book Example 2.20 to see that $\ell^2 \hat\otimes \ell^2$ has a complemented copy of $\ell^1$ -something incompatible with it being the Hilbert-Schmidt operators.

Comment: Btw, the first argument works even if you don't believe $H \hat\otimes H$ to be the trace class.

Comment: Oh, I see. I had a serious confusion about the meaning of the symbol $H\hat{\otimes}H$. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: No problem. The first two chapters of Ryan's book should be enough for you to get familiar with quadratic forms over Banach spaces

Answer (score 0):

Certainly false. Here's a counterexample: Let $A_1 = B_1 = e_1$ and $A_2 = B_2 = e_2$ where $e_1, e_2 \in H$ and are orthonormal. Then 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^2 \langle A_i, B_i\rangle = 2$$
but,
\begin{align}
\Big\| \sum_{i=1}^2 A_i \otimes B_i\Big\| 
&= \sqrt{\langle e_1, e_1 \rangle\langle e_1, e_1 \rangle + \langle e_1, e_2 \rangle\langle e_1, e_2 \rangle + \langle e_2, e_1 \rangle\langle e_2, e_1 \rangle + \langle e_2, e_2 \rangle\langle e_2, e_2 \rangle} \\
&= \sqrt 2
\end{align}
which is a contradiction.

Comment: The second norm is the Hilbert-Schmidt norm.